# Monitoring network requests using Firebase performance on ionic, capacitor, angular

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, capacitor, firebase-performance

I'm using Firebase performance monitoring in my android application built with **ionic/capacitor/angular**.
I've got Firebase metrics and traces implemented and working, But I'm getting no data related to network requests. Wondering if it's possible to monitor network requests in a non-native application?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

After some research, I found out that it is possible to monitor network requests. But for this the network requests must be sent natively, e.g. with OkHttp3. For example In Angular, you can create an HTTP interceptor that forwards each request from the HttpClient to the plugin.Of course it takes some effort. But as far as i know, this is the only solution.